# Keep Browser-Plugins from manipulating HTML

Tags: javascript, browser, plugins

**my question is:** Is there a way to keep browser-plugins from manipulating the HTML or at least the HTML of a specific div?

**Background information:**

I built a CMS with AngularJS. When saving a site in the CMS, the application looks for the HTML-code in a specific div (#content) and sends this to the server.

I have problems with browser-plugins, which manipulate the HTML. When a user edits his site, and has e.g. Grammarly-plugin installed, Grammarly adds some code to the HTML, which is then sent to my server and saved in the database.

When I then look at the clients site, there is the Grammarly-code.

**Hope you can help me, thanks in advance!**

Comment: Are you storing any HTML that gets sent? You could have an XSS vulnerability. Should users be entering any HTML in this field? Perhaps you could strip all HTML before saving it to the DB.

Comment: The HTML is stored in a database. The user doesn't enter HTML by hand, but makes changes in the HTML via the editor (click on a text and rewrite it for example). Of course technically advised users could manipulate the HTML over the browser, which then would get stored too. But I'm checking for XSS.